# What is this "The?" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> When I had free time, I would think of **the** new girl at school.

Is this "the" the same as in:

> "**the** new kid of **the** block?"

Answer (score 7):

*The* is a definite article. Its use indicates that the phrase is about a specific, singular instance of the noun which follows *the*.

*The new girl at school* refers to one specific girl: the one who most recently began attending the school.

*The new kid on the block* refers to the particular child who most recently appeared on the block.

The two phrases have similar structures and convey the same sort of idea. Both refer to the newest member of a specified group. You can break them down like this:

> [The] [new girl] [at school]
>
> [The] [new kid] [on the block]
>
> [One particular] [most recently joined person] [within some domain]

To answer your question directly, yes, *the* is being used for the same purpose in both phrases.

Aside: I've changed *new kid of the block* to *new kid on the block*, which is more idiomatic. We typically think of someone residing *on* a city block rather than being part *of* it.